# Notebook refusing to use headset microphone over built-in webcam mic

Tags: windows-7, audio, webcam, microphone, headset

I'm running Windows 7 on an MSI GX740 notebook with Realtek's HD Audio drivers (updated) and recently purchased a Turtle Beach X12 headset.  The headset's mic is analog, and when I plug it in my system recognizes a new audio device but seems to continue recording from the built-in webcam mic instead of the headset.

Before answering "open Recording Devices and select the headset microphone", my Recording Devices screen only shows one microphone, even when the headset is plugged in, and always records from the webcam instead of the headset.  Disabling it and/or enabling any of the other options doesn't seem to help.

Also important to note is that USB microphones work fine, because they show up in the Recording Devices and I can set them as the default device.  Also, I've tried other analog microphones/headsets and get the same error, so it's not the headset.

Any idea how to disable the webcam mic in favor of the headset or why the analog headset is not showing up?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Recording Devices]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a driver problem.  The driver for the headset is not installed or the current driver software is not compatible with the headset you have purchased.

Another possibility, you might need a driver upgrade for your sound card.